# How to access a table in HTML without any name with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table from url. The table seems to have no name. I have scraped the links and its text to csv using below code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = 'https://www.sbp.org.pk/smefd/circulars/2020/index.htm'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')


anchor = soup.find_all('a',href = re.compile('2020'))


file_name = "Circulars.csv"
f = open(file_name,'w')
header = 'Cir_Name ,Links\n'
f.write(header)

for link in anchor:
    href = link.get('href')
    text = link.getText()
    text1 = text.replace("\n", "")
    f.write(text1.replace(',','|') + "," + href.replace("," ,"|") +"\n")

print("Done")
```

What I need is to scrape the table as it is. currently I am able to get just links. I need other columns too.

I have tried following code but failed. I am able to get to the table but thats not enough

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = 'https://www.sbp.org.pk/smefd/circulars/2020/index.htm'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')


table = soup.find_all('table',attrs={"width": "95%",'border':'0','cellpadding':"1"})



tablee = soup.find_all('tr',attrs={'table',attrs={"width": "95%",'border':'0','cellpadding':"1"}})



print(tablee)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save data to CSV, you can use this example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.sbp.org.pk/smefd/circulars/2020/index.htm'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.select_one('table[width="95%"]:not(:has(table))')

all_data = []
for row in table.select('tr:not(:has(td[colspan]))'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True).replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', ' ') for td in row.select('td') if td.get_text(strip=True)]
    tds += [row.find_previous('td', {'colspan': '4'}).get_text(strip=True).replace('\n', ' '), row.a['href']]
    all_data.append(tds)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Its quite nice. Can you please explain the code and what I was missing.

Comment: @Husnain The main problem is selecting the _right_ `<table>`. The site is made completely with nested tables - so this is the main challenge. After that, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: What does this mean 
`('table[width="95%"]:not(:has(table))')`

and this
`table.select('tr:not(:has(td[colspan]))')`

Comment: @Husnain It's CSS selector...`'table[width="95%"]:not(:has(table))'` will select innermost `<table>` with attribute `width=95%`. Innermost means that this `<table>` doesn't contain other `<table>`s

Comment: SImilarly the second line mean the `table row` which has no `table data` with `colspan`

Am I right?

Comment: @Husnain `table.select('tr:not(:has(td[colspan]))')` selects from this table every `<tr>` that doesn't contain `<td>` with attribute `colspan=`

Comment: Can you please explain this too `tds = [td.get_text(strip=True).replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', ' ') for td in row.select('td') if td.get_text(strip=True)]
    tds += [row.find_previous('td', {'colspan': '4'}).get_text(strip=True).replace('\n', ' '), row.a['href']]`

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only one table in the page, it is not necessary to provide the `attributes`. U can simply do

```
table = soup.find('table')
```

in order to get the table. Then, u can do whatever u want with the table.

Hope that this helps!

Comment: It is nice to know. But can u help in extraction of table as csv

Comment: Sure...Will provide u the solution within 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

use lambda. Gives you the table + rows.

```
table = bs.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='table') 
rows = table.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name=='tr')
```